# Problems with operator << in a Singleton Log class

Tags: c++, unicode, singleton, operator-keyword, ostream

I'm trying to implement a Meyers Singleton log class that uses a '<<' operator to allow something like this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SLog& log = SLog::getLogInstance();
    log << output::screen << "Test" << endl;
}
```

[Yes, I understand that `_tmain()` is a monstrous Windows hack - I'm just trying to learn this stuff and that's the easiest way for me to push unicode for now; I'll worry about cross-platform later]

My problem is that my template function NEVER gets called; it always seems to call into the base `wostream` instead.  Here's more information about the implementation:
--SLog.h--

```
enum class output : int
{
    screen = 0,
    file,
    both
};

class SLog
{
private:
    TOSTREAM* m_pO;
    output m_Output;

    SLog();         // Private ctor; no instantiation allowed
    ~SLog();        // Private dtor; no way to kill it
    SLog(SLog const&) {};   // Private copy ctor; copying is a no-no
    SLog& operator = (SLog const&) {};  // Private - no assignations
public:
    template<typename T>
    TOSTREAM& operator<<(const T& statement)
    {
        switch (m_Output)
        {
        case output::file:
            if( NULL != m_pO )
                *m_pO << statement;
            break;
        case output::both:
            TOUT << statement;
            if( NULL != m_pO )
                *m_pO << statement;
            break;
        default:            // default to screen
            TOUT << statement << " like a boss...";
            break;
        }

        if (NULL != m_pO)
            return *m_pO;
        else
            return TOUT;
    };

    TOSTREAM& operator<<(const output& statement);
    static SLog& getLogInstance();
};
```

And here's the SLog.cpp:

```
SLog & SLog::getLogInstance()
{
    static SLog log;
    return log;
}

SLog::SLog()
{
    m_pO = new TOSTREAM(TOUT.rdbuf());

    // Initially set the output to go to the screen
    m_Output = output::screen;  
}

SLog::~SLog()
{
    // Is our logging output stream still good?
    if (NULL != m_pO)
    {
        m_pO->flush();  // flush it, in case there's still output
        delete m_pO;    // free the memory I allocated in the ctor
    m_pO = NULL;    // Set it to null to be sure we can't use it
    }
}

TOSTREAM & SLog::operator<<(const output & statement)
{
    m_Output = statement;
    if (NULL != m_pO)
        return *m_pO;
    else
        return TOUT;
}
```

I've defined TOUT, TOSTREAM and so on here:

```
#if defined(UNICODE) || defined(_UNICODE)
#define TERR        std::wcerr
#define TOUT        std::wcout
#define TSTRING     std::wstring
#define TSSTREAM    std::wstringstream
#define TOSTREAM    std::wostream
#define TOFSTREAM   std::wofstream
#define TNPOS       std::wstring::npos
#define SPRINTF     swprintf_s
#else
#define TERR        std::cerr
#define TOUT        std::cout
#define TSTRING     std::string
#define TSSTREAM    std::stringstream
#define TOSTREAM    std::ostream
#define TOFSTREAM   std::ofstream
#define TNPOS       std::string::npos
#define SPRINTF     sprintf_s
#endif
```

[The `<< " like a boss..." <<` was added just to see if I was calling into my function as I tried various things to get it to print out; it never did and when I set my breakpoint and walked through, I was only going through the base `wostream` implementation...]

So, I'm obviously not the C++ programmer I thought I was; what am I doing wrong here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to test the trivial case.

```
log << "Test" << endl;
```

outputs

```
Test like a boss...
```

as you expect.
But

```
log << "Test" << " more test" << endl;
```

outputs

```
Test like a boss... more test
```

Your stream insertion operators return `TOSTREAM &`, so only the first item goes to the `SLog`.

They should return a `SLog&`, i.e. `*this`.

```
SLog & SLog::operator<<(const output & statement)
{
    m_Output = statement;
    return *this;
}
```

The other operator left as an exercise.

Comment: I actually tried that when I was trying to figure out what was going on.  The problem is that returning an `SLog&` won't allow a compound statement like `log << "TEST01" << endl;`; the `<< endl;` gives `no operator "<<" matches these operands.  operand types are: SLog << <unknown-type>`.  Both `<iostream>` and `<iomanip>` are `#include`d.  When I try to compile, I get a similar `C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`.

Comment: @KennG `std::endl` is a function template. You can add an overload for it. (You'll need all the overloads that `std::basic_ostream` has if you want it to be used exactly like one.)

Comment: Just to finish up, I used your advice (THANK YOU) and did some more digging and ended up with the following (that works, just in case anyone else ever tries to do this):
`SLog & SLog::operator<<(TOSTREAM &(*manip)(TOSTREAM &))
{
    switch(m_Output)
    {
    case output::both:
        manip(TOUT);
        if(NULL != m_pO)
            manip(*m_pO);
        break;
... (for brevity)
    default:
        manip(TOUT);
        break;
    }
    return *this;
}  // With appropriate header
SLog & operator<<(std::_Smanip<std::streamsize> _Smanip){return *this;};`